# Getting Potential Leak of an object in CVPixelBuffer

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios4, memory-leaks, screen-capture

i am creating a app to screen capture from the iphone. So after i did the coding i used profiling and analyzing to check memory leaks. I am getting only one memory leak in one section in the code. Here is my code which gives me the memory leak.

```
-(void) writeSample: (NSTimer*) _timer {

if (assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
    // CMSampleBufferRef sample = nil;

    CVReturn cvErr = kCVReturnSuccess;

    // get screenshot image!
    CGImageRef image = (CGImageRef) [[self screenshot] CGImage];
    NSLog (@"made screenshot");

    // prepare the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
    CFDataRef imageData= CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image));
    NSLog (@"copied image data");
    cvErr = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                         FRAME_WIDTH,
                                         FRAME_HEIGHT,
                                         kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                         (void*)CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData),
                                         CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),
                                         NULL,
                                         NULL,
                                         NULL,
                                         &pixelBuffer);
    NSLog (@"CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes returned %d", cvErr);

    // calculate the time
    CFAbsoluteTime thisFrameWallClockTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    CFTimeInterval elapsedTime = thisFrameWallClockTime - firstFrameWallClockTime;
    NSLog (@"elapsedTime: %f", elapsedTime);
    CMTime presentationTime =  CMTimeMake (elapsedTime * TIME_SCALE, TIME_SCALE);

    // write the sample
    BOOL appended = [assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTime];

    if (appended) {
        NSLog (@"appended sample at time %lf", CMTimeGetSeconds(presentationTime));
    } else {
        NSLog (@"failed to append");
        [self stopRecording];
        self.startStopButton.selected = NO;
    }
  }
}
```

it says Potential leak of an object stored into 'imageData'. Can any one help me with finding the error in the above code. There is a memory leak in above code when i check it with the memory management tools too. If any one can help me it would be a great help.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Do a `CFRelease` on your `imageData` when your done with it?

Comment: @yeesterbunny is correct. Are you releasing this imageData anywhere in your code

Comment: Nop i m currently not CFReleasing the imageData any where in the code. Can u specify some code sample how to do CFRelease and if it is ok to CFRelease it in end of the method. Bcs its looping several times. By the way thanks for your quick response.

Comment: CFRelease(imageData); i guess this is what you saying me to do right? :)

Comment: when i do CFRelease at the end of the method app getting crash.

Comment: Crash? What does it say? You can put it right before or right after `NSLog (@"CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes returned %d", cvErr);`

Comment: yeah its crashing on Tread6 and the tread name is com.apple.videotoolbox.preparationQueue and its getting EXE_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: @SameeraChathuranga where did you put `CFRelease(imageData)`?

Comment: Exactly the place u mentioned above. After NSLog (@"CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes returned %d", cvErr);

Comment: @yeesterbunny dude its soo strange .. lol ... CFRelease(imageData) cause app crash when i did it in one MAC and its working well in another MAC .. soo strange .. how ever it worked .. Thanks .. can u put it as a answer and i can accept it as a answer.

Comment: That is odd....okay I'll put it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From comments -

Do a `CFRelease` on your `imageData` when your done with it?

You can put it right before or right after `NSLog (@"CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes returned %d", cvErr);`

```
CFRelease(imageData);
```

Comment: is your problem solved? how to release pixel buffer after added to assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor?

Comment: Old answer but if you get the crash, you need to do the CFRelease when you stop using the pixel buffer, I do it after calling CVPixelBufferRelease

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferRef/Reference/reference.html

I am not sure about the rest of the code you have, but generally when there is a call with Crete as a word in it, it has to have a corresponding release statement. Please check the documentation above.

> ### CVPixelBufferRelease
>
> Releases a pixel buffer.
>
> ```
> void CVPixelBufferRelease (
>    CVPixelBufferRef texture
> );
> ```